# Multiple upload image using managed_file

Tags: forms, files, media

I'm trying to do a very simple thing (seems not that simple at all) in my custom form, to add multiple files using the managed_file form api. Like in the admin, select a file, upload, then a new input file appears.

But I can't achieve that... do I need a callback ???

```
    'gallery' => array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',  
        '#name' => 'gallery[]',
        '#title' => t('Gallery'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
        ),
    ),
```

Thanks

Comment: Could someone also provide a Drupal 7 answer?

Comment: For drupla7 below code will work
$form['file'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#name' => 'files[]',
        '#title' => t('Upload some photos'),
        '#attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple'),
    );

Answer (score 7):

In Drupal 8, add '#multiple' => TRUE

Example:

```
$form['images'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#upload_location' => 'private://images/',
  '#multiple' => TRUE,
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'),
    'file_validate_size' => array(25600000),
    'file_validate_image_resolution' => array('800x600', '400x300'),
  ),
);
```

More about form api: [Introduction to Form API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api)

Answer (score -1):

Complete [details](http://www.michaelbagnall.com/blogs/managed-files-within-drupal-7) of upload multiple images using from API

```
/**
 * our example system settings form
 */
function mf_settings_form($form,&$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['managed_file_example'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Managed File Example'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('managed_file_example',''),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://managed_file_example/',
  );

  $form = system_settings_form($form);
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mf_settings_submit';

  return $form;
}
```