# How to upload multiple files in a custom form with Form API

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, files

I have a custom form created with Form API. In this form, I have a file field with the type `managed_file`

```
$form['fichiers_justificatif'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'justificatifs',
    '#upload_validators' => $validators,
    '#upload_location' => 'private://justificatifs',
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#description' => 'types de fichier autorisés : png gif jpg jpeg pdf doc',
);
```

It works well, I can upload a file, get its name and url.

But I don’t know how to have a multiple file upload like the one with see in admin or with the webform module.

Example of webform module which handle multiple files upload :

[image]

I’ve tried to add `'#multiple' => TRUE`, but I have an Ajax error after  the 2nd file is submitted.

I’ve tried this module [Multi-value form element](https://www.drupal.org/project/multivalue_form_element) but still have AJAX issue.

I’ve tried dropzone.js but I'm not satisfied with it since it adds an other interface for file (different from the one in admin). User are confused there is an other interface for files.

What could be the better way to handle this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some #states not working for custom field but do work on identical webform field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298319/some-states-not-working-for-custom-field-but-do-work-on-identical-webform-field) - This question does not directly answer how to upload files, but it shows you how to use the custom, more advanced FormAPI Elements from Webform module.

Comment: `#multiple` works, at least for these 6 people who, like me, upvoted this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/226326/47547. Could be a conflict with other Ajax code on your site.

Comment: @4k4  thank you for confirming me that `#multiple`works. I will try to debug my AJAX issue then. In my form, I uses some custom services and I see in the Ajax error  that the 2nd file cause an Ajax call to those services which initially works. My issue seems to be related to this issue.

Comment: @4k4 So since you confirm me that `#multiple works`, I was able to debug the Ajax issue. The answer that helps me : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212928/why-doesnt-the-ajax-callback-call-the-class-contructor#answer-212943 (use `protected` instead of `private` for my custom services).